# Multi-type ArrayList as function argument in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I want to send an array list containing multiple types to a function (I know it is not a good practice, it is on purpose).

I don't know what type should I use for the 'numbers' argument of the function. And then how to iterate over it. I tried List but that needs a .

Thanks.

```
fun sum(numbers : ArrayList) : Double
{
    var sum:Double = 0.0

    for(i in 0 until numbers.itemCount)
    {
        var temp:Double = numbers.getItem(i).toDouble()
        sum = sum + temp
    }

    return sum
}

fun main()
{
    var ar = listOf("99", 1, 3.1)

    println(sum(ar))
}
```

Comment: You can use `List<Any?>` if you want to have a list containing any objects. It gets tricky when you want to do something with those elements, in your example it seems these are convertible into numbers, in that case I'd suggest to do that conversion before populating the list.

Comment: @al3c: I was trying to show polymorphism in functions. It appears it cannot be done this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this without checking specific types. `String.toDouble()` is not the same function as `Number.toDouble()` even though they look the same. Your `ArrayList` type has to be `Any` to be able to accept both `String`s and `Number`s. Then you have to explicitly check the type. You will have to handle the case where something is not a String or a Number by throwing an exception.

You might as well make the type `List<Any>` instead of `ArrayList<Any>` to avoid the unnecessary restriction on input.

```
fun sum(numbers : List<Any>) : Double
{
    var sum: Double = 0.0

    for(item in numbers) {
        val temp = when (item) {
            is String -> item.toDouble()
            is Number -> item.toDouble()
            else -> error("Unsupported type")
        }
        sum += temp
    }

    return sum
}
```

There is an existing `sumBy()` function for lists, so you can simplify this code:

```
fun sum(numbers : List<Any>) : Double = numbers.sumBy {
    when (it) {
        is String -> it.toDouble()
        is Number -> it.toDouble()
        else -> error("Unsupported type")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to show polymorphism in functions. So I cannot do it that way (because of the differences of toDouble methods).